# Is 'clamp' with two positional arguments a common convention?

Tags: math, conventions

Someone submitted a patch to a project I work on that adds a math clamp function, supporting:

- `clamp(number)`: where min=0.0, max=1.0
- `clamp(number, min)`: where max=1.0
- `clamp(number, min, max)`.

Is `clamp(number, min)` a convention? It's not something I've seen before.

Comment: I've not seen it before. And I'd be inclined to reject all but the last of those functions on the grounds that a statement like`clamp(theta, 0, 2 * pi)` is perfectly self-explanatory, while `clamp(x)` and `clamp(x, 0.5)` just aren't.

Comment: I think its a common term in (electrical) engineering.

Comment: @dmuir the question is about conventions for arguments to use.